# Displaying user info session from mongo

Tags: javascript, mongodb, vue.js, express, passport.js

I need to displaying user info : (firstname, lastname, photo....) on my vue sidebar, i successfully set passport.js for the authentification but i need to display like that :

[image]

### ... and When i try to have a render, the variable has not converted :

[image]

That my model **UserModel.js** :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  googleId: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  displayName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  image: {
    type: String,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
  }

})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
```

**userRoute.js** :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passport = require('passport');
const router = require('express').Router();
const auth = require('../auth');
const User = mongoose.model('User');
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const UserModel = require('../models/UserModel');

router.get('/current', auth.required, (req, res, next) => {
   const { payload: { id } } = req;

  return User.findById(id)
    .then((user) => {
      if(!user) {
       return res.sendStatus(400);
    }

     return res.json({ user: user.toAuthJSON() });
     });
 });
 
 module.exports = UserRoute;
```

**auth.js** :

```
 const jwt = require('express-jwt');

 const getTokenFromHeaders = (req) => {
    const { headers: { authorization } } = req;

    if(authorization && authorization.split(' ')[0] === 'Token') {
       return authorization.split(' ')[1];
          
     }
     
     return null;
   };

    const auth = {
      required: jwt({
      secret: 'secret',
      userProperty: 'payload',
      getToken: getTokenFromHeaders,
  }),
    optional: jwt({
      secret: 'secret',
      userProperty: 'payload',
      getToken: getTokenFromHeaders,
      credentialsRequired: false,
     }),
  };

 module.exports = auth;
```

**app.js :**

```
const path = require('path')
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('...')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const passport = require('passport')
const session = require('express-session')
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo');
const connectDB = require('config/db.js')
const UserAPI = require('../backend/routes/userRoute')
const port = 5000

// Load config
dotenv.config({ path: '.env' })

// Passport config
require('passport.js')(passport)

connectDB()

const app = express()

// Body parser
app.use(express.json())

app.use(
 session({
   secret: 'keyboard cat',
   resave: false,
   saveUninitialized: false,
   store: MongoStore.create({mongoUrl: process.env.DB_URI,}),
 })
)

// Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

// Set global var
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.user = req.user || null
  next()
})

//routes
app.use('/auth', require('/auth.js'))
app.use('/api-user', userAPI)

app.listen(port, () => console.log('server running at http://localhost:${port}'))
```

Comment: Did you mean `const Users = mongoose.model('User');` instead of `const Users = mongoose.model('Users');`?

Comment: @Mana-Shah my bad i wanted to say `const User = mongoose.model('User')` I will fix that